# How to release memory after replacing big data in python?

Tags: python, memory

I use python to rewrite several hundreds-of-MB files. And it's very quick. Memory of my mac is 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3, processor is 2.5 GHz Intel Core i7.

But here is the problem. When I want to rewrite another file. Suddenly, I can't even open the file which has several hundreds of MB data fluently. And the processing is quite slow.

Does it because I haven't released the memory? Why does my mac become so slow, even just open a file after I rewrite some files?

FYI, I use textmate to write python. And I am really new to python.

Comment: Do you close the files after writing them?

Comment: Sorry but my crystal ball is out for repair... But if you post your code we might have a chance to spot the problem.

Comment: I want to import some data into mongodb. I have some .dat files, and there are some special symbols in the file, like"::"(double colons). I use python to rewrite double colons to comma. Here is my code: 'with open('ratings.dat') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        line = line.replace('::', ',')
        print line'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python has got a built-in garbage collector, that automatically frees memory used by variables you don't need any more. So, that *shouldn't* be a problem with memory.

But if you're not closing these files they remain open and some of their contents is in memory (Python interpreter thinks you're going to use them).

First of all, check whether you're closing your files properly

```
f=open("file.txt")
a=f.read()
f.close()
```

Or even better

```
with open("file.txt") as input:
    data=input.read()
```

Here the file's closed automatically.

If some of your variables gets very big you can delete it manually: `del data`

Comment: I even restarted my mac, but it was still very slow. Last night I spent a whole night to rewrite the data. Now I tried your code, and there is no result. It seems recovered